Check whether T is a function type
I have been able to emulate some C++ traits like is_null_pointer, is_integral, is_floating_point, and is_array with _Generic, but am at a loss at is_function.
Is it possible to emulate is_function in C? Say given an expression, I'd like _Generic to evaluate to 1 if it is a function name, else 0. And as a function name and a function pointer are interchangeable in most cases, the behavior should be the same for a function pointer.
I need this because I have some macros that expect a function. I'd like to assert at compile-time that the argument is a function.

I am open to using C23's typeof, or any other feature.

Re “Say given a function name, I'd like _Generic to evaluate to 1 if it is a function type, else 0”: The expression 1 satisfies the requirement that, given a function name, it evaluates to 1 if it is a function type and to 0 otherwise. Perhaps you would prefer an expression that evaluates to 1 when given an identifier that is a function name and to 0 when given an identifier that is not a function name. However, what if it is a pointer to a function? Or, does it need to handle the case where the identifier is not a function or object name, such as a type name or enumeration constant?

@EricPostpischil In the context of _Generic (and well, most others), wouldn't a function name and a function pointer be interchangable? It'd be nicer if the solution can work with both. As of a type name, that'd be nice too. Enumeration constants wouldn't have anything to do with functions, so not really relevant, unless I have misunderstood your point?

@EricPostpischil I've updated the question to change "function type" to "function name".

https://godbolt.org/z/Wf3sYG4fn

@pmg That works for one particular function pointer type, but not in general.

There is no "general function pointer type". All function pointers include return and argument types.

@pmg Interesting. I am looking to make this _Generic work for any function.

It works for any function with specific return and argument types (which are the only function pointer types that exist in C).

@pmg "There is no "general function pointer type". All function pointers include return and argument types." ==> Then I'd conclude that is_function() might not be possible to implement in C, given that there is no generic function type that is compatible with any other function type.

From cppreference: "Types like [...] pointers to functions don't count as function types." so it appears to be the same as in C ... I don't know (or wanna know) C++

I know this has been asked before and if I remember correctly none managed to answer it then, at least not with pure ISO C.

How about this (ISO C23):
#define IS_FUNCTION(T)         \
  _Generic((T),                \
    typeof(T)*: true,          \
    default :   false)

The trick here is that there are only two types in C that "decay" whenever used in an expression, arrays and functions. An array will however decay into a pointer to the first element, while a function will decay into a pointer to that function type.
The operand of typeof does not cause decay. So if passing an array like int [10] to the macro, The (T) will decay into int* but typeof(T) will give int [10]. And then in turn typeof(T)* will be an int (*)[10].
But in case of a function, you end up with a function pointer during typeof(T)*, the same type as (T). And in case you pass an explicit function pointer, then typeof(T)* is a pointer to function pointer.
Some tests:
#include <stdio.h>

#define IS_FUNCTION(T)         \
  _Generic((T),                \
    typeof(T)*: true,          \
    default :   false)

#define TEST(T) printf(#T " is %sa function\n", IS_FUNCTION(T)?"":"not ")

void func (void);

int main(void)
{
  int (*fptr)(void);
  int array[10];
  int x;

  TEST(func);
  TEST(main);
  TEST(fptr);
  TEST(array);
  TEST(x);
  TEST(nullptr);
}

Output:
func is a function
main is a function
fptr is not a function
array is not a function
x is not a function
nullptr is not a function


I can't say if it's ugly or beautiful. Typical C

@anatolyg Anything causing the reader to go WTF is probably ugly, so... But then function-like macros are already ugly in themselves.

Unless C provides us with a better way, we make do with what we have.

Agree with @Harith. Why can’t we get simple predicate out of the box, defined by the standard : valuetype(x) == array/pointer/function/variable/union/structureg. Same for querying storage (auto, function, file, extern, thread-local).

@Lundin I posted some type traits for review on Codereview. I thought you might like to see them, and in the process, point out some bugs/wrong behaviours/pitfalls that I have failed to realize. Assuming you'd like to see, here's the link: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/292516/type-traits-for-c-with-generic Good day to you.

As commenters already pointed out, C99/C23 do not have good, simple way test for "pointer-ish", "function-ish", .... You can get some mileage using GCC extensions. In particular __buiiltin_types_compatible_p.
The fine print:

you can check if the passed parameter is a function returning a specific type: int, int*, ...
Tested with GCC 11.4 and 9.3. Might work with CLang. Could not find any C23 compatible solution using _Generic - as noted in comments - _Generic rejects function types with error message.

The example below shows a is_i_function macro, which can identify functions returning int, regardless of the parameters to the function. The is_The macro will return false for any variable, even an int variable.
Hope it provide (at least partial) solution to the OP. Might be possible to extend - see note at bottom.
#include <stdio.h>

        // helper to get type
static int int_func() { return 1 ;} ;

#define is_i_function(name) __builtin_types_compatible_p( __typeof(int_func), __typeof(name))

    // Will be detected as 'int returning function'
int ii_func (int x, int y) { return x+y ; }
    // Will be rejected as it does not return an int.
char chr_func(int a, int b) { return a+b ; }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int int_var ;
        printf("int_var=%d\n", is_i_function(int_var)) ;
        printf("int_func=%d\n", is_i_function(int_func)) ;
        printf("ii_func=%d\n", is_i_function(ii_func)) ;
        printf("chr_func=%d\n", is_i_function(chr_func)) ;
}

Output:
user@beelink2:~/proj/78599133$ ./a.out
int_var=0
int_func=1
ii_func=1
chr_func=0

In theory, possible to define all kinds of predicate for various types, and create is_function (is_int_function(...) || is_chr_function(...) || is_double_function(...))

"Generic rejects function types with error message" How come? While the C standard says that "The type name in a generic association shall specify a complete object type other than a variably modified type.", it won't matter since if you pass a function it decays to a function pointer, which is an object type.

@Lundin - I read too much into gcc warning I got from putting function name into _Generic(…). Probably other mistake.
